# Is it possible to install my iPhone's WhatsApp on Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, applications, jailbreak, whatsapp.app

I'm using iOS 8 with jailbreak on iPhone and Yosemite on Mac.

Can I install WhatsApp on my Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install Bluestacks on your Mac and then install the Android version which you could access through BlueStacks.

Here's [how to install it](http://machow2.com/whatsapp-for-mac/).

Comment: Thank you but my phone is iPhone 5 and has iOS 8. Why should I install Android?

Comment: @user1213807, I interpreted Zero's comment to mean that you can install WhatsApp on your mac, by installing the Android _version_ of WhatsApp on your Mac using BlueStacks, which must be some kind of Java/Android emulator service for OS X.

Comment: Please summarize answers instead of just posting a link. Links can break rendering your answer useless.

Comment: It is correct that whatsapp can run on mac using an emulator called bluestacks, the only thing is that you cannot have one account on pc/mac and smartphone simultaneously. You would constantly have to verify the change between your smartphone and computer by typing in a code send to your phone, which sometimes can take up to an hour or more. I have tried it and do not recommend it. But... whatsapp for your browser is in development!

Answer (score 1):

No ,whatsapp did not create any software for the mac, so you cant install whatsapp on your system .Currently they only have developed the software for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

(As of jailbroken iOS 8.4 and WhatsApp version 2.12.4)
If you have a jailbroken iPhone you can.

1. First make sure your phone is jailbroken per the instructions [here](http://www.redmondpie.com/ios-8.4-jailbreak-release-update/)
2. Install WhatsApp Web Enabler from Cydia
3. Go to settings, WhatsApp Web Enabler and enable it.
4. Open WhatsApp (it may crash, just reopen it and you're good), touch the QR code
5. Navigate to https://web.whatsapp.com, scan the QR code

Done! You can now use whatsapp from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can now install [WhatsApp's official desktop app](https://blog.whatsapp.com/10000621/Introducing-WhatsApps-desktop-app) on your Mac.

It is important to note that it uses your phone as a "server" for your messages; whenever you open it after setting it up, it will need to connect to your phone in order to load and be able to send/receive messages. This is because it needs to load the messages from your phone, not WhatsApp's own servers, as messages are not stored on their servers.

Answer (score -3):

You can use Whatsapp on MAC, read here how to do that: https://www.techgreet.com/whatsapp-on-mac-and-window-pc/

Comment: Please summarize answers instead of just posting a link. Links can break rendering your answer useless.

Comment: This is also about bluestacks

Answer (score -3):

You can use Whatsapp web version or install Genymotion on your Mac then use Whatsapp there.

1. Whatsapp Web version (only for Google Chrome): https://web.whatsapp.com/
2. Genymotion: genymotion.com

Source: [Whatsapp for Mac OS X](http://lovewhatsapp.com/tutorials/download-whatsapp-for-mac-os-x)

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. Also, sending people off to Google isn't really helpful. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.